# How to use Auth() in custom class Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I created custom class in Laravel and try to use object `Auth()`:

But I can not get access to this object: `Auth()->user()->id`.

I tried to use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
```

Comment: Could you please provide the way you implemented the custom class? Is the custom class included in the app container? If it does you should be able to use any facades without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Facades, you don't need to specify the whole namespace, just

```
use Auth;
```

Then, you should be able to use this in your custom class:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Alternatively, there is a globally-accessible [auth() helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-auth) that you can use without the Facade at all:

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

Comment: When I use this I get null

Answer (score 0):

Try `Auth::user()`. This wil return a user object, so you can do `Auth::user()->id` or `Auth::user()->email`;